# Responsive Design, Css Breakpoints

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I'm **making a site** and I'm making it **responsive**, i would like to know if it's **better to use breakpoints** **at real devices size** as in this image **or setting breakpoints on each "breakpoint**" in which the **design doesn't work**[image].

Answer (score 2):

breakpoints at real screen sizes are unpractical as its nearly impossible to cover all sizes/ devices.. also you have to keep in mind that the browser size is not necessarily the actual screen size.. i would just set the breakpoints to make the design work.

Answer (score 1):

You could have 4 to 5 breakpoints. The ones that I usually use and work well are for:

Extra small devices(Phones) (<768px)
Small devices(Tablets) (≥768px)
Medium devices(Desktops) (≥992px)
Large devices(Desktops) (≥1200px)

Since real device sizes vary, it's nearly impossible to cover all devices.

Comment: yeah but i'm also using breakpoints for 1440/1366/1280...

Comment: You can add an extra breakpoint that targets all large screens. For eg @media(min-width: 1280px){}. This will work for all screen sizes above 1280px instead of having 3 separate breakpoints